# Which is better in asp.net 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-2.0, themes

Can anyone tell me themes are better or CSS style sheets are better in asp.net for design?

Please explain the concept also with an example.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this previously asked question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504299/best-practices-css-or-themes-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should combine them. Use your css files in the theme folder for your normal styling of all the html elements in your website (include all the generated elements).

In the skin file of a control, you can set the default css class. Other properties like the layout and default behaviour of the elements (sample: calender control) are editable here too.

Skin files are good for all layout specific configuration you can't easily do with css, but with the .net properties of the controls.

Answer (score 3):

A theme can specify both .skin files and .css files. So there no reason not to use themes.

As for skins versus css: **Go for css** if its css'able.

Answer (score 0):

Basically themes is built for server controls. You can not use themes with html controls.
The css is used for server controls,html controls and tags. If you are using only server controls then you can use "theme" because you can enable or disable theme on control basis, page basis and whole website basis. 
    In my opinion CSS is best way to design website. because after rendering theme it shows the css style with controls and tags.
You can also use "Theme" and "CSS" together.

Answer (score 0):

Same query is avilable at my post at following link.

[ASP.NET 2.0, AppTheme: How can we utilize AppTheme in best way for my ASP.NET WEBSITE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163211/asp-net-2-0-apptheme-how-can-we-utilize-apptheme-in-best-way-for-my-asp-net-we)

**It make you happy**